# iOS Enterprise Program and iOS Developer Program

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a question about the licenses of iOS and my application.

I am developing a application to run on a lot of iPad's for a consulters company. This company will download the (IPA) file from our web interface, and sync the devices on iTunes. Is this possible with the simple iOS Developer Program licence? I think that this is the famous ad-hoc, and not the in-house distribution from Enterprise Program. I am really confused about this licence and the Enterprise Program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 4 was released, you don't have to manually download the IPA and sync through iTunes, you can install by tapping on a link on a web page.  You just need to create a plist file and point the link to it with a special pseudo-protocol.  The details are in the developer library.

The individual / company developer account can handle that with ad hoc builds, but it sounds like the enterprise program is a better match for your needs.  Ad hoc builds expire after a few months, it's limited to a hundred users and getting the UDIDs from the client can be a real pain.  I've gone down that path before, and it's not unusual to receive UDIDs as screenshots of iTunes embedded in a Word document or incomplete/wrong, even *after* you give them step-by-step instructions on how to do it properly.

The enterprise program has its own drawbacks.  It can take a while to get set up, and the company needs a DUNS number.  However once it's set up, you'll find it easier to work with.

Comment: We don't have the DUNS number. If I have > 100 devices, may I create more accounts of single iOS Developer?

Comment: You can, but it quickly becomes a hindrance and Apple may take a dim view of it if they notice - this isn't what that program was intended for.  You can't sign a single IPA so that it will run for everybody, so you'll have to maintain multiple IPAs and keep track of which devices are registered with which account.  If you need to distribute in-house to more than 100 devices, I strongly recommend getting a DUNS number.  It's free if you don't mind waiting a month, or you can pay for one to be processed immediately.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have the last question: We are a digital agency, nevertheless we can join the iOS Enterprise Program or our contractor need to do this? Thanks again!

Comment: If I'm understanding your situation correctly, your client should join, as it's members of that organisation that will be running the app.

Answer (score 1):

The standard developer program will let you distribute to 100 devices per year. That's the ad-hoc mechanism, and it isn't intended for what you're doing, although it certainly will work assuming you have fewer than 100 users.

The Enterprise program is designed for what you're doing, but costs more and has different details.

Answer (score 1):

With the individual and company plans you have a limitation of 100 devices that you authorize with ad hoc distribution. Besides you have App Store access. If the number of devices is > 100 then applying to this program is not useful and then you must revert to the enterprise program.

The enterprise program gives you unlimited number of devices that can be authorized but no access to the App Store. In such case the consulter company must be enrolled to this program and can distribute the apps only to its employers or members. Finally this program provides other than ad-hoc distribution even in-house distribution, that is a form of automatic app distribution (like a simplified app store but for the company only). Finally note that in order to apply to this program the company must own a DUNS number.

Clearly if you want to have both options, that is in-house distribution and App Store access the company can enroll to the two programs.